# Why is %fd an invalid string for url decoding?

Tags: javascript, decodeuricomponent

Why is %e9 or %fd invalid string to decode using the decodeURIComponent from Javascript?

These characters appear in the middle of a string and I can't understand where the problem is. They are valid hexadecimal characters.

Full string (this is part of a string sent by client app to server and that was being blocked by modsec):

```
%61%e9%3d%36%7f%00%00%01%00%00%43%fd%a1%5a%00%00%00%43
```

Sample to decode:

```
decodeURIComponent("%61%e9%3d%36%7f%00%00%01%00%00%43%fd%a1%5a%00%00%00%43")
```

Error:

```
VM222:1 Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

I am using these two functions to encode base64 and decode from base64 (from here:[Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64)):

```
function c64(t) {
        return btoa(encodeURIComponent(t).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,
                (match, p1) => {
            return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
        }));
    }

function d64(t) {
        return decodeURIComponent(atob(t).split('').map(function (c) {
            return '%' + ('00' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-2);
        }).join(''));
    }
```

The original string is in base64:

```
d64("Yek9Nn8AAAEAAEP9oVoAAABDYek9Nn8AAAEAAEP9oVoAAABD")
```

returns:

```
...js:1 Uncaught URIError: URI malformed
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: I think URL encoding is supposed to use UTF-8 encoding, and those may not be valid UTF-8 values.

Comment: Please post the whole string as well as the code that generated it.

Comment: Right.  The original RFC only allowed ASCII characters (0x00 to 0x7F).  There is a suggested extension to allow UTF-8 encoding, and that's commonly used.  Arbitrary binary data is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for the update! "*the original string is in base64*" - what was the string that you passed to `c64` to generate that string?

Comment: "*was being blocked by modsec*" - maybe modsec is right, this is actually an invalid request. Are you certain it originated within your app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the unicode representation of that character in hexadecimal encoding is not `"%e9"` or `"%E9"`.

Start by typing in console:
`"\u00e9"` or `"\u00E9"`

which is % replaced by `"\u00"` in your example. You will get:

`'é'`

You can verify this by running:

`escape('é') //"%E9".`

Now run

`encodeURIComponent('é')`

and you will get `"%C3%A9"` not `"%E9"`. This is because `encodeURIComponent` returns hex dump of bytes. If the character is 2 bytes you get `%xx%yy`, if 3 bytes you get `%xx%yy%zz`.

Try this with `"€"`. First do:

`escape("€")`

, you will get `'%u20AC'` or same as `"\u20AC"`.

To get the hex dump of its byte code run:

`encodeURIComponent("€")` and you will get `'%E2%82%AC'`.

[This example from Wikipedia 'UTF-8' article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Examples) explains in detail how `'%E2%82%AC'` is calculated. It is the hex dump of `11100010 10000010 10101100`.